# Laravel Backpack::crud set permission (role) to a category

Tags: laravel, permissions, crud, roles, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to set Role (or permission) to my category in Laravel Backpack (newscrud).
I have added the field of Role in CategoryCrudController class and category_role table in DB and set relations in Category and Role models.
the relation data is now stored in the table, although the checkbox remains unchecked!

```
$this->crud->addField(
        [
            'label' => 'Roles',
            'type' => 'checklist',
            'name' => 'roles',
            'entity' => 'roles',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => "Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role",
            'pivot' => true,
        ]
    );
```

[Added role field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcDJf.jpg)

Now I want to allow the users with the granted role to use crud on the category's articles.
I know I can use hasRole and use denyAccess() in CrudController's setup function but it doesn't what I want.

```
public function setup(){
   if (backpack_user()->hasRole('certainCategoryRole')) {
     $this->crud->denyAccess([ 'delete','edit','write']);
   }
}
```

I need to give articles operations access to users by their category's assigned role.

Can anyone help?

Thanx